# Auto-updating "importrange" spreadsheet on Google site

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

hope someone can help me with this...

I've imported a range from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B.  When I change data on A, it quickly updates on B- all's good there.  I embedded both spreadsheets A and B on a Google sites page, and embedded spreadsheet A updates fine, but spreadsheet B doesn't show the new data in Google sites, even though the actual sheet does change.

I notice that if I create a graph or some such change inside of spreadsheet B, the embed on the Google site then updates completely.

Any ideas how to make this happen automatically?
Bill

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Data Range to update value on the Column on the spreadsheet.
 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=FR#setValue(Object)

you import data with Import range ,  and you take all data with the Class Range  and you put data on others columns.